# Regulated functions with $0$ measure that cannot be approximated by step functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, step-function

**Questions**

I am looking for some counterexamples for properties that of functions that are commonly mistaken for being true in cases where they do not hold in general. The specific cases I am thinking of are the following:

> Give an example of a regulated function $f$ (that can be approximated by a sequence of step functions $\phi_n$) on $[0, 1]$ such that $f (x) ≥ 0$ for all $x ∈ [0, 1]$, $\int_0^1f(x)dx = 0$, and such that $f(x_0) > 0$ for at least one $x_0 ∈ [0,1]$.
>
> Is there an example which is not a step function?

**Attempt**

My initial idea for the first part of the problem is to define a step function on a suitable partition $P=\{p_0,p_1,...p_n\}$ as $\psi(x)=0$ for any $x \in (p_{i-1},p_i)$, and $\psi(p_i)=1$ (at the endpoint of each subinterval).

My initial idea with this problem the second part of the problem is to define a sequence of step functions $\phi_n=1$ on the interval $\big{[}1,\frac{1}n\big{]}$ and $0$ otherwise. Then as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we say that $\psi \rightarrow f$ and so this provides an example that is not a step function.

---

Are these examples fine, or do they violate the definitions in some way that I am not seeing? The main concern I have is with the second part. I know that the integral/area should be converging to $0$, however, I'm not convinced that it is equal to $0$ in the same way that it was with the original step function (since this was a set of points rather than a thin strip).

Comment: What definition of step function are you using? For some authors, functions like the Dirac delta function quality as step functions and so would your $f$ (these authors allow a partition like $[0, 1] = [0, 1) \cup [1, 1]$ for the domain of a step function).

Comment: The interval is partitioned over open subintervals $(p_{i-1},p_i)$. The definition of a step function that I am using states that the values at the end points of each partition have no constraints on what values they can take (besides remaining in the codomain). @RobArthan

Comment: So your example where $f$ is the characteristic function of $\{1\}$ is itself a step function by your definition.

Comment: Would it be possible to modify the step function so that it is equal to $n$ on the interval $[0,\frac{1}n]$ so that f meets all of the required properties but is no longer a step function?@RobArthan

Comment: Your new proposal gives a function to the extended reals and then metric notions like uniform convergence don't make sense. As @B.S.Thomson has pointed out, something like the Thomae function is the way to go.

Comment: Regulated functions are uniform limits of step functions. Alternatively they are functions that have right and left hand limits at every point.   So take any function which is zero except at a particular sequence of points.  Clearly this is regulated with a little work and answers your question.   Much more interesting is the Thomae function (aka popcorn function) is regulated. All regulated functions are Riemann integrable. And that is the most famous example of a nonnegative, regulated function with a zero integral but which is positive only on the rational numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @B.S.Thomson. Is it the case that *every* function that is $0$ everywhere (except for being strictly positive at a finite number of a points on $[a,b]$) are regulated?

Comment: " Is it the case that every function that is 0 everywhere (except for being strictly positive at a finite number of a points on [a,b]) are regulated?"  Yes.  But those are step functions.  I advise learning very fast that the usual definition of regulated is functions with one-sided limits everywhere and then proving that they can be characterized as uniform limits of sequences of step functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Thomae Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) is a regulated function with $0$ integral. This is a regulated function and is therefore Riemann integrable. The values of the function are greater than or equal to $0$ (strictly positive where $x$ is rational).

See below, a plot of values on the interval $(0,1)$ (with the highest point in the middle at $(\frac{1}2,\frac{1}2)$ - taken from the Wikipedia page linked above.

[image]